# Consuming Class Library C# in my webSite

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a class library and now I want to consume it on a website.

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace FeedPath
{
    public partial class ClassFeed : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public void ParseFeed(string builtUrl, int maxFeed, string code)
        {
            System.Net.WebRequest myRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(builtUrl);
            System.Net.WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
            System.IO.Stream rstream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
            System.Xml.XmlDocument rdoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            rdoc.Load(rstream);
            System.Xml.XmlNodeList ritems = rdoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");
            string title = "", link = "", sdescription = "";
            string staticstring = code;
            for (int i = 0; i < maxFeed; i++)
            {
                staticstring = staticstring + i;
                System.Xml.XmlNode rdetail;
                title = "";
                link = "";
                sdescription = "";
                rdetail = ritems.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("title");
                if (rdetail != null)
                {
                    title = rdetail.InnerText;
                }
                rdetail = ritems.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("link");
                if (rdetail != null)
                {
                    link = rdetail.InnerText;
                }
                rdetail = ritems.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("description");
                if (rdetail != null)
                {
                    sdescription = rdetail.InnerText;
                }
                Response.Write("<li id='" + staticstring + "'><h3><a href='" + link + "' target='new'>" + title + "</a></h3>" + sdescription + "</li>");
                staticstring = code;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

then on .aspx i use

```
<% string fd01Url = "https://bitly.com/u/l3ny.rss"; ParseFeed(fd01Url, 7, "bl"); %>
```

I added the reference, but now I'm having trouble initializing it.

I'm trying:

```
using FeedPath;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FeedPath.ClassFeed Myopject = new.FeedPath();

    }
}
```

But with no luck.

The image below is the class I made:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A couple of things to make sure you ask good questions: include the actual code in the question itself. This is meant as a resource to help everyone, not just you. Your image could be unavailable to future viewers of this questions. You also need to show all relevant code, not just a tiny snippet. Please edit your question to provide this information.

Comment: Your "class library" contains a class that inherits from Page. Why ?

Comment: I guess i wasn't putting all the code. my bad. @sh1rts i'm Neophyte im not sure but i think because i use <% string fd01Url = "https://bitly.com/u/l3ny.rss"; ParseFeed(fd01Url, 7, "bl"); %> on the abc.aspx page? not sure and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is all wrong, that's why.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FeedPath.ClassFeed Myobject = new FeedPath.ClassFeed();
    // use `Myobject` to call instance methods. For example:
    Myobject.ParseFeed(...);
}
```

It's also worth noting that since you've already added `using FeedPath;`, you can call `ClassFeed` without using the fully qualified namespace. So this would also work:

```
using FeedPath;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClassFeed Myobject = new ClassFeed();
}
```

I'd suggest you go through some C# tutorials/walkthroughs and properly learn the basics of the language before continuing on your project.

Comment: every tutorial it's referent, i think if you aren't willing to help you shouldn't opine. and thank you anyway.

Comment: @l3ny Yes, every tutorial is different, but they will still teach you most of the basics of the language. And how am I not willing to help? My answer contains the solution to your problem. Going through a tutorial was merely a suggestion, one that you can decide on whether to follow or not.

Comment: Yes you are right, i just felt because i am learning researching i was suppose to feel less. but yes you have the right solution thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Alright. I will take a shot at this one.

You need to be able to instantiate your FeedPath class. This is done with the `new` command. 
Then you call your methods with your variable in this case `myObject.ParseFeed()`

```
using FeedPath;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FeedPath myObject = new FeedPath();
        myobject.ParseFeed() //Fill the () of your .ParseFeed() method with your parameters.    
    }
}
```